# jquery how to remove the wrapping div?

Tags: jquery, jpeg

i have this:

```
<div class="test"><div id="123"><img class="image" src="1.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="test"><div id="123"><img class="image" src="2.jpg"></div></div>
```

what i want to do is `if(img.attr("src") == ("1.jpg"){ remove the entire div that hosts that image}` to become like this:

```
div class="test"><div id="123"><img class="image" src="2.jpg"></div></div>
```

the divs have the same class.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** Updated answer to reflect changes in question

One line is all it takes :)

```
$('img[src="1.jpg"]').parents('div.test').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Or

```
$('img[src="1.jpg"]').closest('div.test').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: what if the img is like this `<div class="test"><div id="123"><img class="image" src="1.jpg"></div></div>` how can i remove the div with the class `test`

Comment: you'd use `.parents('div.test')` instead of parent. You could also use `.closest('div.test')`

Comment: You can do `parentsUntil()`:http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/  -- that should be exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with the div selector would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img[src='1.jpg']").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Removes the parent div for the image where it's src = '1.jpg'

```
$('img[src="1.jpg"]').closest('div.test').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img[src='1.jpg']").parent().remove();

<div class="test"><div id="123"><img class="image" src="1.jpg"></div></div>

$("img[src='1.jpg']").parent("div").parent("div.test").remove();
```